# I am used api with ionic and i face some issue about that .can you please explain me how we use the api in ionic?

Tags: c#, ionic-framework

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-home',
        templateUrl:'./home.page.html',
        styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
        })
    export class HomePage implements OnInit {
        requestObject:any=null; 
        constructor(private http: HTTP) {}
        ngOnInit(){}
        getRequest({
            this.http.get(url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
                parameters:{},
                headers:{}
            ).then(onfulfilled:res=>this.requestObject =res.data)
            .catch(onrejected:err=>this.requestObject=err);
}}
```

Comment: error in getRequest function?

Comment: Can you tell us what the issue you are having is?

Comment: Hi jon, my issue in onrejected&onfulfilled are not define ,what is this?

Answer (score 0):

on the getRequest code you have

```
getRequest({
        this.http.get(url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            parameters:{},
            headers:{}
        ).then(onfulfilled:res=>this.requestObject =res.data)
        .catch(onrejected:err=>this.requestObject=err);
```

The last 2 lines:

```
.then(onfulfilled:res=>this.requestObject =res.data)
```

and

```
.catch(onrejected:err=>this.requestObject=err)
```

should mean (I haven't touched angular in a while) that if the request has no errors you call **onfulfilled**, but if you have errors you call **onrejected**.

you need to define these 2 functions in your code for Angular to call them at the appropriate time.